# Какой из вариантов правильный?

Tags: пунктуация

1)«В какой город прибудем?» – спросил водителя. «Флорес – ответил он и пояснил: город-остров». 2)«В какой город прибудем?» – спросил водителя. «Флорес» – ответил он, и пояснил: город-остров». 3)«В какой город прибудем?» – спросил водителя. «Флорес», – ответил он, и пояснил: «Город-остров».

Answer (score 2):

Правильного варианта нет. Если в авторских словах внутри прямой речи имеются два глагола со значением высказывания, один из которых относится к 1 части прямой речи, а другой ко второй, то после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире,первое слово 2 части с прописной буквы:

*«В какой город прибудем?» – спросил водителя. «Флорес, – ответил он и пояснил: — Город-остров».*

Comment: «: -»... Тут что-то жмёт.

Comment: Что именно "жмёт"? Говорит-то один человек, но фразы две. Чтобы не разделять кавычками две его реплики, всю речь берём в кавычки, а вторую фразу оформляем как реплику - вместо кавычек тире.

Comment: На тире не похоже.

Comment: Ну, это уже техника печатания, хорошо, что вообще вижу что-то и даже печатаю...

Comment: Понимаю: вас тут много, а у меня — всего один палец.